# Get google maps api usage info

Tags: google-maps, google-api

we using some google maps api's, and we wan't to add gapi usage/quotas to our monitoring system. Does Console api has it's own api for retrieving that metrics?
Maybe other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current API endpoint to get the current quota usage information of your API. The only way to check the quota used by your application is by checking your own [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). You can also see here the traffic (number of request per seconds), and error ratio of the enabled API of your project.